# In a shell script, write the input parameters to a json file

Tags: bash, shell, io

I have multiple python scripts and I use >> to write the results into a file 'eval.json'. Meanwhile, I would like to record the parameters passed in this command. Since there are multiple commands in the script, I am wondering how I could do it.

I have tried echo and '>>' but I am not sure how to approach it.

```py
python -m example --k 2 --width 1500 --height 3000

python -m example2 --x 3 --y 4
```

I would expect the result in the 'eval.json' be something like:

```
{"k" : "2"}
{"width": "1500"}
{"height":"3000"}
{"result": "something"} (print statement in the python script)
{"x":"3"}
{"y":"4"}
{"result2":"something"}
```

We don't have to worry about the commas in the json file because I have a way to handle it in another script which handles this.

Comment: do you want to convert a file to json? did i get that right?

Comment: Yes. By >> at the end, I actually could do it.

Comment: so the issue is solved?

Comment: No, I meaned by using >> I could create a json file. But I still don't know how to write the parameters to the file.

Comment: Your python program has to print them, to stdout if that's what you are appending to the end of those files.

Comment: the variables that are passed can be called in a shell script with the help of $1,$2$3 and so on. does this help?